# How do I install Clojure on a Guix System?

Tags: guix

After running

```
guix system install clojure
```

I find that there is no `clojure` or `clj` on my `$PATH`.

I was told on the #guix@freenode IRC that one can get the path to the contents of a package by running `guix build $package`. So I ran

```
ls $(guix build clojure)
```

only to find that there was only a `share` folder in there. What gives? There seems to be no binaries in the Clojure package!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the `clojure` binary was only added 16 days ago, 2020-11-20. Before that there was no user facing binaries in that package. Running `guix pull` and `guix install clojure` solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the tipoff - I didn't realise it had been added!

Comment: See also: https://issues.guix.gnu.org/37929